# Looking for textbooks that consist primarily of questions

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know of books which have lots of questions, whose formats are "fill in the holes" type?  The same goes for the theorems and exercises. I am looking at pure math, especially Real analysis, Abstract Algebra, Topology, etc.

Answer (score 2):

in calculus I hope this can help you 
Exercises and Problems in Calculus
John M. Erdman
Portland State University
Version August 1, 2013

c 2010 John M. Erdman
[Exercises and Problems in Calculus](http://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/CALCULUS/CALCULUS_pdf.pdf)

Comment: Sir... can u plz tell me... hw do u write maths equation i  this website

Comment: sorry just put dollar sign first and end of your equetion

Comment: @Arpan Mukherjee . i'm so sorry for my english language mistakes I am ashamed. i wrote wrong in my last comment .
but i can't delete it .and about your comment : just put your mathematic equation in 2 dollar sign first and end of it and you will see the changes, for more equetion you can read this post [link] (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) I hope my comment can help you

Comment: No need 2 apologise sr... thanks 4 ur cmmnt

Answer (score 2):

Putnam and Beyond is a great resource for problems in core undergraduate math. Also, Concrete math is a great book full of problems( it covers the material through problems, so if you cover up the solutions, you have what you looking for.

Concrete Math can be found online, Google it to take a look.